# inbound-gateway. Elimination Url params which is after last dot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I'm using following configuration to create an api endpoint in spring integration.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway 
  request-channel="httpProjectRequest" 
  reply-channel="httpProjectResponce" supported-methods="GET" 
  path="/project/{key}" payload-expression="#pathVariables.key">
   <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" produces="application/json"/>
 </int-http:inbound-gateway>

 <int:service-activator 
  ref="projectAPI" 
  method="get" 
  input-channel="httpProjectRequest" 
  output-channel="httpProjectResponce"/>
```

Problem which I'm facing is when i send GET request on `/project/DFV-1.1` URL in "key" value I get `DFV-1`, when i send GET request on `/project/DFV-1.1.1` in key value is get `DFV-1.1`

Why it is ignoring value which is after last dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, configure a bean like:

```
<beans:bean id="integrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping"
            class="org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"/>
</beans:bean>
```

That `useSuffixPatternMatch` description:

```
/**
 * Whether to use suffix pattern match (".*") when matching patterns to
 * requests. If enabled a method mapped to "/users" also matches to "/users.*".
 * <p>The default value is {@code true}.
 * <p>Also see {@link #setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(boolean)} for
 * more fine-grained control over specific suffixes to allow.
 */
public void setUseSuffixPatternMatch(boolean useSuffixPatternMatch) {
```

Comment: then i always get following msg in response `{
    "timestamp": 1495809411330,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/project/DFV-1"
}`

Comment: As an answer to which request, please?

Comment: GET request `http://localhost:8090/project/DFV-1` Headers `Content-Type`:`application/json`

Comment: Hm... Works for me. I have `/test/{value}` as a pattern on gateway and I send `/test/aBc-1`. Indeed the `payload` is `aBc-1`. But I use Spring 5 though...

Comment: May be thats the reason. I'm using spring 4. I have added some detail to question please check if it will create any difference to result.

Comment: Have just switched to `4.3` and both `aBc-1` & `aBc-1.1` works well for me. With the `useSuffixPatternMatch = true` (default) I indeed get the latest `.1` stripped down. Something else goes around in your application...